# Append Excel files to Pandas Dataframe from multiple paths, one path works but the other does not?

Tags: python, pandas

So I have code to append a large number of excel files from various directories to their respective dataframes so I can run some comparisons. The code for these two paths is effectively identical, except for the individual paths which I copy/pasted in from their respective directories.

```
    In[2] path1 = r'C:\Users\me\Documents\Python Scripts\1
          files = os.listdir(path1)'

    In[3] path2 = r'C:\Users\me\Documents\Python Scripts\2
          files = os.listdir(path2)'

    In[4] Files1 = [f for f in files if f[-3:] == 'xls']

    In[5] Files2 = [f for f in files if f[-4:] == 'xlsx']

    In[6] for f1 in Files1:
          data1 = pd.read_excel(path1 + r'\\' + f1)
          data1['Date_Created'] = np.full([len(data1.MPN),1],f1[15:23]).astype(str)
          df1 = df1.append(data1)

    In[7] for f2 in Files2:
          data2 = pd.read_excel(path2 + r'\\' + f2)
          data2['Date_Created'] = np.full([len(data2.MPN),1],f2[15:23]).astype(str)
          df2 = df2.append(data2)
```

The issue I'm running into is that it works just fine for input 7 but not for input 6. I've run each separately in different notebooks and it appends the files I need but for some reason it only works for the second dataframe here. The first doesn't return an error, but rather returns a blank dataframe. Is there any reason it won't pull files from the first directory?

Comment: Try replacing `files = os.listdir(path2)` with `files += os.listdir(path2)` in line 3.

Comment: That actually worked really well. Is that generally how it's done for additional directories?

Comment: Your code for parsing the files is presumably correct. The error originated when you overrode the `files` variable instead of appending to it, basically a typo. Alternatively, you could run lines in this order [2,4,6,3,5,7] and it would work. Is this what you are asking for?

Comment: Now I get it. I was just trying to clarify what type of error it was for future reference, now I get it was an order of operations thing haha, thank you again!